# Microservices - How to ensure referential integrity?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, microservices

I'm creating a personal expenses manager app. In order to do so, I'm creating some microservices and I'm adopting the "[database per service](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html)" pattern. So, I have:

- Expense database

  - Columns are: id, category_id, name, amount, payment_date, details

---

- Category database

  - Columns are: id, name

**The problem I'm facing right now is:** one expense can (and should) have one category. If the services have their own databases, how can I ensure that a given expense has an existing category? The only way I can imagine right now is:

At expense's creation time, I make a request to categories service in order to validate category's existence. But I can clearly see a big flaw with this approach: It may work well with a single relationship, but what when I have four more? Performance wise, it would be a mess calling five other services to ensure integrity.

I have no idea on how to deal with this problem. Any advice on how to solve this the better way?

Comment: by not segmenting your microservices into its smallest parts. Divide them up into buisness areas, and not by "tables" or data. Microservices are not tables in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> one expense can (and should) have one category. If the services have their own databases, how can I ensure that a given expense has an existing category?

Broadly, you don't.  Which is to say, information that needs to be consistent must be stored in the same place (ie, part of the same "microservice").  You only distribute data across multiple databases when it doesn't have to be consistent.

One sort of compromise that is sometimes acceptable is that we can store in the expense database a cached copy of the category information.  That allows you to think about adding constraints that the expense data must be consistent with the cached copy of the category data, provided that you can deal with the fact that the copy of the category data will be stale, and may be invalidated by changes made to the category data.

But enforcing referential integrity has a problem with race conditions; I submit an expense in a category that "really" exists, but hasn't appeared in the cached copy yet.  What should happen?  "A [microsecond difference in timing](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/) shouldn’t make a difference to core business behaviors."

Another sort of compromise is to model time -- an expense on Tuesday can use a category that was valid on Tuesday, even though it was no longer valid on Wednesday.  So the expense service can suspend judgement until it knows whether or not the category is valid at the appropriate time.  This makes sense when changes to expense policies are planned in advance.

Another sort of compromise would be to re-organize the implementation of your business capabilities, so that the behaviors associated with category are all performed by the service that manages that data.  The expenses service would know about the identifier, but very little else.

There is no magic - distributed systems require compromises.

Comment: "... information that needs to be consistent must be stored in the same place" - What about a user table tied to a user creation/deletion service and many other microservices that relate to the user attributes and preferences (whether user specified or otherwise), tied to a foreign key of user id. If suddenly the user / user id is deleted in main user table, other tables with user preferences (and user id as FK) lose referential integrity. But at same time, storing all this data in same place might not make sense. Thoughts?